# cublas address out of bounds for particular matrix size

Tags: cuda, cublas

When I run the following code to compute the matrix multiplication y = X * B:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "cublas_v2.h"


using namespace Eigen;

int main(){
  int N = 240000;
  int K = 3;
  int p = 9700;

  MatrixXf X_host = MatrixXf::Zero(N, p);
  MatrixXf B_host = MatrixXf::Zero(p, K);
  MatrixXf y_host(N, K);

  float *X_dev;
  float *B_dev;
  float *y_dev;

  cudaMalloc((void**)&X_dev, sizeof(float) * p * N);
  cudaMalloc((void**)&B_dev, sizeof(float) * p * K);
  cudaMalloc((void**)&y_dev, sizeof(float) * N * K);

  cudaMemcpy(X_dev, X_host.data(), sizeof(float)*p*N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(B_dev, B_host.data(), sizeof(float)*p*K, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  cublasHandle_t handle;
  cublasCreate(&handle);

  cudaError_t error = cudaGetLastError();
  if(error != cudaSuccess)
  {
    std::cout << "CUDA error: " << cudaGetErrorString(error) << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "No problem before cublas call\n";
  }

  float alpha = 1.0;
  float beta = 0.0;
  cublasSgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, 
              N, K, p, &alpha, 
              X_dev, N, B_dev, p, &beta, y_dev, N);

  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  error = cudaGetLastError();
  if(error != cudaSuccess)
  {
      std::cout << "CUDA error: " << cudaGetErrorString(error) << std::endl;
  }

  cublasDestroy(handle);
  cudaFree(X_dev);
  cudaFree(B_dev);
  cudaFree(y_dev);
  return 0;
}
```

I got this error from `cuda-memcheck`:

```
========= Invalid __global__ read of size 4
=========     at 0x00000a88 in void gemmSN_NN_kernel<float, int=256, int=4, int=2, int=8, int=4, int=4, cublasGemvTensorStridedBatched<float const >, cublasGemvTensorStridedBatched<float>>(cublasGemmSmallNParams<float const , cublasGemvTensorStridedBatched<float const >, float>)
=========     by thread (223,0,0) in block (190,0,0)
=========     Address 0x2b660269807c is out of bounds
```

There are about 100 such address out of bounds error, and the number of them varies between runs. The problem disappears when I set K to be a larger number (for example 10). Anyone has an idea what might be going on? I'm using CUDA 10.1, P100 on CentOS 7. Thanks!

Update on September 21, 2020:
This issue is gone after I updated to CUDA 11.

Comment: I am able to reproduce the issue.  My guess is that you have uncovered a defect in CUBLAS.  According to my testing, the problem is still present with CUDA 10.2.89 (currently, latest).  If I switch to a Volta V100 GPU, the problem disappears.  It is evident that under the hood, CUBLAS is using different kernels to implement this operation on P100 vs. V100, and I suspect this is the reason for the difference in behavior, and also the reason why I don't immediately suspect a defect in your code, although I haven't studied it carefully. You may wish to file a bug report at developer.nvidia.com.

Comment: This is expected to be fixed in the next public CUDA release (after 10.2.89).  I won't be able to answer any further questions about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, this would appear to be an internal issue in the CUBLAS library. I would editorialize and guess that they don't have test coverage for this unusual dimension problem with such a small inner product dimensions and this bug passed through pre-release testing undetected.

As is usual with likely bugs, your best best is to submit the code in your question as a repro case on a ticket with the [NVIDIA developer portal](https://developer.nvidia.com/).